# Xcode 6 beta 4 Build error - just created app : "Command ibtool failed with code 255"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ibtool

In order to start learning Swift, I installed Xcode 6. I created a "Mobile App" Project and just built it. Without writing any code, I have the following build error :

```
"Command
/Volumes/Xcode/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool
failed with exit code 255".
```

I searched a lot and did not find any solution to this problem... I don't know if it comes from the iPhone Emulator or from the linking with static or shared libraries. 
Does anyone got this issue ?

EDIT: Problem resolved. It was because I had special characters in my name (not in the id). So, I had to connect in iTunes and change "é" to "e".

Comment: Possibly a provisioning profile or certificate issue.

Comment: This is it ! It came from special characters.

Comment: You should give the solution not as an edit but as an actual answer. Answering your own question is legal and useful on Stack Overflow. This is a very interesting situation and your problem and solution will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from special characters ("é") in my name. I just needed to log in iTunes and change "é" to "e". Xcode's not helpful sometimes..